# Develop Outlook Addin for MAC using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, email, outlook

I want to develop an addin for Outlook (installed on MAC). I know that I need to use JavaScript... the problem is I don't find any examples for some easy functionality like:

-> Send an email, forward an email, delete an email, add attachment etc...

I need a pointer on how to start and were I can find some references. 
I was on this page https://dev.outlook.com/ but I don't know how or were to use that in my addin. 
If any of you has a starting point for this.. the information I found is really confusing. I would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resource you mention is the right place to go, you probably didn't have a time to read it through. The following would be the key topics for you:

- [Get Started with Outlook add-ins for Office 365](https://dev.outlook.com/MailAppsGettingStarted/GetStarted)
- [Reference API](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/)
- [Understanding API requirement sets](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/tutorial-api-requirement-sets.html)
- [Various topics and guidelines for Outlook Add-ins](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/outlook-add-ins)
- [Outlook Add-in Code Samples](https://dev.outlook.com/Samples/Addins)

This is probably all you would need to start. Now I would like to give you a few hints, based on your description:

- There is no such thing as add-in for Outlook "installed on Mac". Outlook for Mac doesn't have excitability as you think of COM/VSTO for Windows. You may use scripting, which is available through Applescript with limited functionality. And you able to write Outlook Add-in, which with proper "requirements set" will work under Outlook 2016 on Mac. This add-in is not something special for Mac. It will work for Outlook for Web (In your case "Safari" browser) and will work on Windows and even mobile devices. This is concept: write once for Office - works everywhere, where Office supported. Bottom line, don't look specific info for Mac, instead all information for Outlook add-ins related to Mac as well.
- Add-ins for Outlook are not event driven, so you will not find "onSend", "onReply", etc. events. The add-in depend on user invocation only and API target single item only. If you need functionality, like send, forward, etc., you would be better to look at Applescript and Outlook for Mac scriptable API.

Take a time to read, before you ask very broad-wide question. If you have some specific question, I will be happy to answer, but please spend some time on resources I already provided.